# Entity Framework Core - Fluent API not configuring model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've been trying to get the fluent API working to configure my model. I can't find what's wrong.
It does not seems to enforce any of the constraints but I can see the code run when the model is created. The Documentation says that the Fluent API will override any previous annotations i.e take priority.

Things are working when I use Data annotations in the model.
Here is a simplified example of code that works (In Model - Data annotation) vs one that doesn't (In Context - OnModelCreating).

```
//In Model
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace ParkingPermitData.Models
{

    public class PermitPurchase
    {
        public int PermitPurchaseId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ParkingPermitNumber { get; set; }
        public string PurchaserName { get; set; }
    }
}

//In Context
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ParkingPermitData.Models;
namespace ParkingPermitData.Data
{
    public class ParkingPermitContext : DbContext
    {
        public ParkingPermitContext(DbContextOptions<ParkingPermitContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<PermitPurchase> PermitPurchases { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<PermitPurchase>().ToTable("PermitPurchase");

            modelBuilder.Entity<PermitPurchase>()
                .Property(b => b.ParkingPermitNumber)
                .IsRequired();

        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the code in OnModelCreating as a single statement along with many other variations of this which I have found in examples.
I was trying to setup some more complex relationships and annotations than this but wondered why they weren't working, then tried this very simple case.
It's very frustrating and I would appreciate any help with this please.

One thing to note is i'm using the InMemoryDatabase for the DBContext in early development.

```
//Startup
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ParkingPermitContext>(opt =>
                            opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("ParkingPermitPurchases"));
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Many thanks,
Paul

Comment: So, using this setup you still can insert record with ParkingPermitNumber set to null? Also, no need to use attribute [Required] once you use fluent API

Comment: Yes Olegl. My thoughts exactly and this is my problem. If I comment out or remove the [Required] i can insert nulls. If I debug I can see the code being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In memory database disregards db constraints as it is not a relation database. In particular

> InMemory will allow you to save data that would violate referential integrity constraints in a relational database.

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory)

for more information on what is supported

Comment: Thanks tchrikch.It seems that something that is a very useful time saver cost me some time.